# Salt bit required

Tags: password, hashsum

I'm trying to figure out if we have in Unix password file N amount of account passwords, how many bits should be used for salt? I understand that most Unix used 56 bit password and some uses 12 bit salt?
can some please help?

Comment: Since passwords are encrypted in different ways on different Unix systems, it would help if you could mention what type of Unix system you're interested in.

Comment: Hi @Kusalananda, thank you for your reply, lets say in classic Unix where adding salt increased the difficulty by factor 4096, based on this factor shouldn't it be 12 bits? so If we have N account at the most on the password file we would need N*12 ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can see 3 parts in the respective field with hashed password (passwd file or master.passwd file or a shadow file). Parts are delimited with `$` character. E.g.:

```
$1$GWetb2Qk$.YQAzi67bE7BtVEhJtcbl0
$2b$08$Lb0jCztlyconZIGRjR6OTOCvCja.0B2XOhrt/tHkt2V5JEcE98TRi
```

First part is for hash alg. type, second is or a salt itself (first example) or a salt info (second example), third part is the salted hash.

And yes, algorithms used are quite different. Can you guess/find out?